# Using regular expression to search for a specific pattern in UNIX

Tags: regex, bash, unix, find

I have file names like
`ABCD20140207090842  ABCD20140207090847  ABCD20140207090849  ABCD20140207090850 ABCD2014556644219268  ABCD20140508525691  tf` in my directory.

I want to search for files with specific pattern. i.e **FileNameYearMonthDayHourMinSec.txt**

Note: files `tf` and `ABCD2014556644219268` should not get matched.

Answer with exact pattern would be appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: I tried few regular expression in find but it didn't match anything.

Comment: It's difficult to make a regular expression that will match onyl dates. For example you're always likely to match February 29th for non-leap year. And it's easier to just match the 39th day of a month as well.

Comment: I tried with the following regex.
"^[A-Za-z0-9_ ].*(19|20)[0-9][0-9](00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)[0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9][0-6][0-9].txt$"

Comment: That regex should do (if your filenames actually end in `.txt`, which the example strings you show don't).

Comment: There seems to be something odd about the first occurrence of `[0-9][0-6]`, only when I replace it with `[0-9][0-6]` (which seems the same) does the expression works for me on regexpal.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on NAME, followed by DATE.txt I get this:

```
find . -regex ".*[19|20][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-2][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9][0-6][0-9]\.txt$"
```

This doesn't account for leap-years though, and could match dates such as 31 Feb.

Comment: Thanks :) Can you use this regular expression in `find` command?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `find` command instead of `grep`. Note that I've added the `.*` at the start to strip the NAME part. You might also need to add `-regextype posix-extended` before `-regex` for your version of `find`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I tried with the same attributes `-regextype` `-regex` previously but couldn't arrive at the answer. You made it!

Answer (score 0):

Change the idea. Here is the script no matter leap years or not.

Using GNU date to identify the date

```
for file in *.txt
do
  time=${file%.*}         # remove suffix and get ABCD20140207090842 
  time=${time:(-14)}      # get the date/time 20140207090842
  time="${time:0:4}/${time:4:2}/${time:6:2} ${time:8:2}:${time:10:2}:${time:12}"      # convert time to: 2014/02/07 09:08:42
  date -d "$time" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo $file
done

ABCD20140207090842.txt
ABCD20140207090847.txt
ABCD20140207090849.txt
ABCD20140207090850.txt
```